# Unwanted multiple backslashes after user input apostrophe

Tags: php

I have this in Wordpress:

```
<p>Welcome, [insert_php]session_start();
echo $_SESSION['your_org']  = $_GET['your_org'] . " - "; echo $_SESSION['choice']  = $_GET['choice'];
[/insert_php] - <b>Your Design Ideas</b></p>
```

If a user enters an apostrophe, eg. Bob's as input in 'your_org' variable, I get this as output:

eg. Bob\\\\'s

Have searched and searched for a solution!

Comment: your php is probably hideously out-dated and running with magic_quotes enabled. You need to upgrade...

Comment: searched and searched? :) Type slash before quote, and you will find solutions, problems. Like Marc B said, php is old too.

Comment: Are they both hosting account issues?  ie disabling magic quotes and upgrading php version. My CP says it's running php vers 5.3.29

Comment: I went ahead and asked my host to update the php and turn off magic quotes. They said they have modified php version to 5.5 and turned off magic quotes for that version.

Comment: Weirdly, that has 'reduced' the problem to 2 backslashes instead of 4! ie. output is now eg. Bob\\'s